# iphone search local xml

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm completely new to xcode development, but I would like some guidance or pointing me to some tutorials on developing a basic App that will allow me to search a local XML file by any of its fields, and display results on a list. Then tapping on one item, it parses the XML and display the record.

Added functionality would be the ability of periodically updating the XML file with newer data, but once I get the basic part working, I will try to figure out the rest.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a tutorial about XML here
http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios